# how to align scanline at 4 byte boundary

Tags: c, image, bitmap, jpeg, libjpeg

I am using libjpeg to decompress my JPEG image and write it to a BMP file. Assuming the image width is being set to 2550 pixels at 24 bits (3 bytes) per pixel, the resulting row width will not be a multiple of 4. How do I align each row at 4 byte boundary?

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
unsigned int bytesPerRow = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.num_components;
unsigned int colColor;
FILE *bmpFile = NULL;

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {

    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    row_pointer[0] = raw_image
            + cinfo.output_scanline * bytesPerRow;
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    for (colColor = 0; colColor < cinfo.image_width; colColor++) {

        /* BMP scanlines should be aligned at 4-byte boundary */

    }

    /* write each row to bmp file */
    fwrite(row_pointer[0], 1, bytesPerRow, bmpFile);
}
```

Comment: Copy it row by row starting at aligned addresses.

Comment: You should just unpack the pixels to rgba or rgbx so that each pixel is aligned, assuming performance rather than storage is more of your concern.

Comment: bytesPerRow = 4 * ((cinfo.output_width * cinfo.num_components + 3) / 4);

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I don't know what you mean by aligned address, but I'll check on that. Thank you. user3528438 I'm not sure how to implement that. I need to do some research first. Thank you. Hans Passant the formula still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

> bytesPerRow = 4 * ((cinfo.output_width * cinfo.num_components + 3) /
>   4); – Hans Passant

The formula is correct as far as rounding up to a multiple of 4 is concerned, but incorrect in using the multiplicand `cinfo.num_components`; according to [USING THE IJG JPEG LIBRARY](https://www4.cs.fau.de/Services/Doc/graphics/doc/jpeg/libjpeg.html):

> You will need output_width * output_components JSAMPLEs per scanline
>   in your output buffer…
>
> The output arrays are required to be output_width * output_components
>   JSAMPLEs wide.

So, it's

```
unsigned int bytesPerRow = (cinfo.output_width * cinfo.output_components + 3) / 4 * 4;
```